# Почему fetch не возвращает данные от сервера в отличие от $.ajax ? Yii2

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii2, fetch

Есть и работает **ajax**-запрос, возвращающий данные от сервера:

```
$('#add').on('click', function() {            
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/add-category',                 
    success: onAddSuccess,
  });

  function onAddSuccess(data) {
    response = data;
  }
}
```

Пытаюсь переписать его с помощью **fetch**-запроса:

```
$('#add').on('click', function() { 
  let response = fetch('/add-category');
  let result = response;
}
```

и получаю

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Response
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost/add-category"
__proto__: Response
```

Но самих данных нет. Прошу подсказать, как их получить?

Yii2, Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
$('#add').on('click', function() { 
  fetch('/add-category')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(onAddSuccess);
});
```